# Bad Request ao fazer login com Passport, Express e NodeJS

Tags: node.js, autenticação, express.js

Estou tentando fazer a autenticação de um sistema mas sempre que eu tento fazer login (post) recebo um  erro:

> 400 (bad request).

No console aparece a mensagem:

> *The character encoding of the plain text document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the file needs to be declared in the transfer protocol or file needs to use a byte order mark as an encoding signature*.

Esta é minha rota que recebe o POST do login

```
router.post('/',
  passport.authenticate('local'),
  function(req, res) {
    res.json({ currentUser: req.user });
    //console.log(req.body);
    //res.redirect('/');
  }
);
```

Comment: Estou passando pela mesma dificuldade. Usando o MDB Atlas. Caso tenha a resposta, por favor pode me falar?